# Capturing commands for documentation?

Tags: command-line, documentation

I plan on configuring an Ubuntu Server via the CLI.
Is there any program that can capture my commands (and perhaps responses)?
Just trying to make documentation more efficient.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utility `script` will make a typescript of a terminal session.  To start it:

```
script
```

Then, run your commands.  When done, run:

```
exit
```

All your commands and the responses will now be in a file called `typescript`.

If any of your commands produce color output, then the typescript file will contain the ANSI sequences used.  You can display the color results with:

```
less -r typescript
```