# How can I write my input down to file?

Tags: command-line, tee

Recently, I needed to write my terminal output down. And I've read this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file) to find the answer. But now, I would like to write my commands down (which I type in terminal, for example:`sudo apt update` etc.) to store the history of what I have done earlier.

**How can I save my input to file and simultaneously run this input?**

P.S. `script` comprises too many rubbish of type: `^[[?` `^[[m` etc. I would like to get more simple way, which saves my commands only.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking about [Capturing commands for documentation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592905/capturing-commands-for-documentation)? Or maybe just how to [View history of commands run in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624848/view-history-of-commands-run-in-terminal)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capturing commands for documentation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592905/capturing-commands-for-documentation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to both display a command line's output on console and save the output into a text file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485495/how-to-both-display-a-command-lines-output-on-console-and-save-the-output-into)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the tee command to write your input to a file and also to stdout, piped to your program. e.g. for bash:

```
tee foo |bash
ls
df
^c
```

So the foo file contains

```
ls
df
```

and bash outputs to your terminal.